# python: Turn dictionary int values into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
num ={'a':45,
      'b':5,
      'c':6
       }
```

and I want to turn it into:

```
num ={'a':[45],
      'b':[5],
      'c':[6]
     }
```

How can I do that? Thank you!

I have tried this way:

```
for letter in num:
    num[letter] = list(map(int, str(num[letter])))
```

but get:

> {'a': [4, 5], 'b': [5], 'c': [6]}

Comment: If you want to create a new dictionary, use a dictionary comprehension. If you want to modify the dictionary in place, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please include some code you've tried to solve this with.

As for the answer, you could use [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```py
>>> {k: [v] for k, v in {'a': 45, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}.items()}
{'a': [45], 'b': [5], 'c': [6]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'll pay attention next time.